# Insert records in a MS Access table

Tags: ms-access

This is a simplified scenario.  I have an Access database with 2 tables: Counties and Crimes.  Counties has only 1 field, County (Text), with 18 unique county names.  Crimes is imported from an Excel table and has 4 fields: ID (Integer, unique), Date_ (Date, short date format), County (Text), and Num_Crimes (Integer).  For each County, Crimes are aggregated by month, which is always displayed as the first day of the month (e.g., 6/1/2021) in the Date_ field of Crimes.  If there are no crimes for a particular County for a particular month, no entries are provided in the Excel table.  What I would like to do is make the Crimes table show a record for every County for every month.  So, if I have 18 counties and 12 months of data, I would like to see 216 records in the Crimes table. Right now, as can be seen in the Crimes screen capture, there are only 20 records. Ideally, for example, every County would have a record for 6/1/2021 and 7/1/2021, and so on.  The value in the Num_Crimes field would default to 0 for those records without actual crimes.  Somehow I need to force additional County and Date values.  I’ve tried all sorts of queries involving one-to-many joins of Counties to Crimes, but can’t seem to get the requisite number of records. Any suggestions? See screen captures.  Thank you! [Counties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53Wul.jpg)
[Crimes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTqxB.jpg)

Comment: Forgot to add that I need to do this in Access.  I cannot add the records in Excel. Thank you.

Comment: You can generate a list of dates from a start year\moth to end year\month. Then you would Cross join this data (table in a subquery) with your county, that constitutes your 216 records to start with. Finally you would left join it to your crimes table to get the counts. Sorry I am giving "how to" rather than SQL code because it is access. Generating that list of dates is the most tricky part for an access user, you could create a "Tally" table in your database and fill it programmatically to contain all first days of month in a range (arbitrary, say from 2020 to 2030). Easy in real databases.

Comment: BTW, your data in access, but do you need to do that within access and\or using VBA only?

Comment: Do you need it as a query or would you be open to having it as a query built report?

Answer (score 0):

This boils down to upserting a bunch of records into the crimes table.  Conceptually you loop through every county on the first day of the month between the start and end dates and if there is data you do nothing and if not you insert a 0.  I find that in Access, VBA is the approach to take for these kinds of repetitive tasks.  Add the following public functions to a code module in your database.  Then adjust them to suit and call FillCrimesTable from whereever. for instance from the immediate window type something like FillCrimesTable cDate("6/15/21"), cDate("6/15/22") and hit enter

```
Public Sub FillCrimesTable(startDate As Date, endDate As Date)
Dim db As Database
Dim countiesRecordset As Recordset
Dim currentMonth, endMonth As Date
currentMonth = DateSerial(Year(startDate), Month(startDate), 1) 'first day of startdate's month
endMonth = DateSerial(Year(endDate), Month(endDate), 1)
Set db = CurrentDb
Set countiesRecordset = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT County FROM Counties ORDER BY County ASC")
Do  'loop current month
countiesRecordset.MoveFirst
Do Until countiesRecordset.EOF 'loop counties'
upsertCrimeTable countiesRecordset!County, (currentMonth) 'bug?() needed to force evaluation of dateserial as date?'
'Debug.Print countiesRecordset!County; ": "; currentMonth '

countiesRecordset.MoveNext
Loop
currentMonth = DateAdd("m", 1, currentMonth)
Loop Until currentMonth = DateAdd("m", 1, endMonth) 'I was having trouble remembering how to include the endmonth '
'clean up '
countiesRecordset.Close
db.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

```
Public Sub upsertCrimeTable(County As String, Date_ As Date) 'access doesn't have the upsert syntactic sugar
 If Not (selectCrimeTable(County, Date_)) Then
 insertCrimeTable County, Date_, 0
 End If
End Sub
```

```
Public Function selectCrimeTable(County As String, Date_ As Date) As Boolean
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim sqlString As String
Dim returnval As Boolean
sqlString = "SELECT Num_Crimes FROM Crimes WHERE Date_ = #" & Date_ & "# AND County = '" & County & "'"
'Debug.Print sqlString 'uncomment to see text and date delimeters
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sqlString)
If rs.EOF And rs.BOF Then 'no records
returnval = False
Else
returnval = True
End If
db.Close
Set db = Nothing
selectCrimeTable = returnval
End Function
```

```
Public Sub insertCrimeTable(County As String, Date_ As Date, Num_Crimes)
Dim db As Database
Set db = CurrentDb
Dim sqlString As String
sqlString = "INSERT INTO Crimes (County, Date_, Num_Crimes) VALUES ('" & County & "', #" & Date_ & "#, " & Num_Crimes & ")"
'Debug.Print sqlString 'uncomment to see text and date delimeters
db.Execute (sqlString)
db.Close
Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```